# Adding items to collection in XAML/code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collections, addition

Adding items to a collection in XAML and code-behind seems a bit weird to me. Can someone explain the logic to me?

Here's my test control class which inherits from ListBox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestControl : ListBox
    {
        public TestControl() : base()
        {
            base.Items.Add("FOO");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm using it in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.ControlTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="389" d:DesignWidth="512">
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl>
            <local:TestControl.Items>
                <sys:String>BAR</sys:String>
            </local:TestControl.Items>
        </local:TestControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I see only "BAR" in designer but when I run the application both "FOO" and "BAR" are displayed. What's the logic here? If I subscribe to Loaded event and add "FOO" there, then both strings are visible also in designer.

In my actual much larger project I'm having the same problem when using a property whose type is ObservableCollection. I.e. when I add "default" items to the collection in my constructor, I don't see them in designer. Only when I run the application.

Also, if I add items to my collection without specifying the collection class name, is that equivalent to Add method call? I.e.:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyClass>
        <local:MyClass.Items>
            <local:MyItem Text="First"/>
            <local:MyItem Text="Second"/>
            <local:MyItem Text="Third"/>
        </localMyClass.Items>
    </local:MyClass>
</Grid>
```

In the above case, I have added one "default" item in constructor and all four are visible when I run my application but not in designer.

Compared to this where I create a new MyItemCollection object:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyClass>
        <local:MyClass.Items>
            <local:MyItemCollection>
                <local:MyItem Text="First"/>
                <local:MyItem Text="Second"/>
                <local:MyItem Text="Third"/>
            </local:MyItemCollection>
        </localMyClass.Items>
    </local:MyClass>
</Grid>
```

In this case, my "default" item is not visible when I run my application since Items property is set with a new collection instance.

Comment: Try using [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) to populate your UI controls instead.

Comment: You might want to add the xmlns of local

Comment: Travis, I forgot to add xmlns:local because I had to copy-paste and combine the code above from different classes. I.e. I have it in my actual code.

Comment: Sheridan, data binding will be used but I would like to know what's causing this "weird behavior". Has it something to do with MyClass not yet being in visual/logical tree when I add my default item in MyClass' constructor. That's the only reason I've come up with so far.

Comment: And is it even recommended to add any default items to a collection, at all?

Comment: *Sheridan, data binding will be used*... then you will have no 'weird behaviour'. When you data bind a collection to the `ItemsSource` property of a container control, you add default items *to the data bound collection*, *not* to the UI control.

Comment: Sheridan, the ListBox was just to demonstrate the situation. I'm not using it in my project. I'm using an ObservableCollection and there are items added in the class constructor to show something on screen when the control is dropped from toolbox.People can use either data binding or add items manually in XAML. Therefore I would like to know should I remove the default items or tell people to set the collection object like in the last code snippet. And most of all, why isn't the default item visible in designer but it's visible when I run the application?

Comment: I.e. it behaves the same with the ListBox example and with my ObservableCollection.

Comment: Hi, ran it in my mind and I think after the constructor has been completed, the Items-collection will be reset to the list in your xaml (no add, jut a complete replacement), so all the adding before is gone. After Loaded event, the collection is initialized with BAR, and adding in Loaded events adds the new item. Hope its understandable what I mean :-)